# Understanding the use of this inside a class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having tough time understanding use of `this` keyword in Javascript.

The other questions on stackoverflow I stumbled upon have been more about calling a method or function using `this` keyword. Like using bind or ES6 arrow function and so on..

So I have this stateful component in React and we are using Axios to intercept request

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import Aux from '../Aux/Aux';

const withErrorHandler = ( WrappedComponent, axios ) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        componentWillMount () {
            this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
            });
            this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({error: error});
            });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
            axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor);
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <Aux>
                    <Modal 
                        //Something
                    </Modal>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </Aux>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

Something like above code, Here in above code we call interceptors which we want to remove when we want componentWillMount (to avoid memory leaks)

For that the instructor did something like this in componentDidMount followed by

```
this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
```

this in componentWillUnmount

```
 axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
```

**[Question]** Can some explain me `this.reqInterceptor` here? like shouldn't we create a constructor and declare it there and then use it (maybe I am thinking it wrong)?

Comment: constructor will always returns you a new instance, which you don't need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question we need a good understanding of structure of `React.Component` first.

React stateful components are well design to leverage a bit of object-oriented programming (though you may achieve the same pattern in other paradigms.) You have `this` which refers to the whole component class at your disposal. You can retrieve or assign values to properties or call bounded methods to the component by referring to `this` within the scope.

In stateful components React executes `componentDidMount()` when the DOM is ready and mounted then according to your code you assign a value to `reqInterceptor` property of the component by `this.reqInterceptor = value...`, **`this` is basically the component that we are returning from our function `function withErrorHandler { return class extends Component {...} }`**.

This is a common pattern to dynamically create components on fly. We can apply same in the following example to demonstrate how this works in the scope of ES6 classes:

```
class Service {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}
function getMyService(extra) {
  return class extends Service {
    getExtra() {
      return extra; // extra value like WrappedComponent or axios
    }
    getX() {
      return this.x;
    }
  };
}

// result
const MyService = getMyService('some extra value'); // Returns the class
const myServiceInstance = new MyService(1); // This is what React does to instantiate your component
console.log(myServiceInstance.getX()); // -> 1
console.log(myServiceInstance.getExtra()); // -> 'some extra value'
```

**Update:**
I updated the above example to be semantically close to `React.Component`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will be called with the `new` keyword, so since the method definition is not in the constructor, you could instantiate multiple objects and you won't register every time a listener.

In this case, he wants to tie the class method to the react lifecycle (`componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount`).